# Does SQL Compact Edition Support Clustered Indexes? [2011 edition]

Tags: sql-server-ce, clustered-index

According to various sources, SQL CE 2.x does not support any kind of clustered indices. However, the current [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) reads "SQL CE databases also support indexing", linking to the [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171986.aspx) as its source.

However, I as not able to verify the existence of *clustered* indices. A quick test in .net 4.0 exceptioned with 'clustered' being unknown. The [edition comparison chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) does not talk about clustering at all.

So, does CE 4 support clustered indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the only supported type of index is NONCLUSTERED http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345331(v=SQL.110).aspx

Comment: Really!? -- Does this include the automatic index created for Primary Keys?

Comment: Yes, but it may not reflect the physical implementation, only the T-SQL syntax